# VS Code Multiple Projects in one window (NOT "add project to workspace")

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to solve the problem of too many vscode windows open at once. Looking for a ui solution that will allow me switch between projects quickly (terminals files etc..)

[image]

Does VS code or any extension allow us to open multiple projects in one window? I can see we can make a workspace with multiple projects but that wont work because things like `cmd+P` or find considers all files in every workspace and i also need a set of terminals unique to whatever the 'current project' is

I saw a tutorial where the guy had a master tab bar at the top. when he clicked one an entire new project was loaded; however i cant figure out how that is done.

Comment: You might want to provide a link to said tutorial.

Comment: cant find it anymore... Was only hoping to describe what i remeber which would ring a bell with someone.

Comment: try this https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sydeslyde.open-in-new-instance

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to **window => merge all windows**
2. Note all the different windows will merge into a hight tab bar

[image]

Comment: In Sonoma I don't have the "Merge All Windows" option :(

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the [Workspace Manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=design4pro.workspace-manager) extension? It allows you to open projects in new or same window

Comment: This sets up a better flow than currently but the terminals dont stay intact..

Comment: I tried a couple of the other extensions (Workspace Explorer) and don't see one that behaves the same. If I find one that does respect the terminal settings I'll def update my answer